# How to get access to parent's DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

how can I get access to a parent's DataContext?

I've got an UserControl containing 3 buttons, which I want to use for several different UserControls - so the user has always the same actions available.

When clicked on button 'Add' I need to do something inside the current DataContext, which isn't much of a hassle since I can just do the following:

```
public void CtrlClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    MyClass2 c2 = btn.DataContext as MyClass2;
    c2.CallCustomMethod();
}
```

When the button 'Del' is clicked I want to delete the object `MyClass2` out of a `List<MyClass2>` which is held in `MyClass1`.
In order to do that I need to have access to MyClass1.

My UI (pseudo code):

```
Window (DataContext = base)
  Grid
    UserControl uc1 (DataContext = base.MyClass1)
      Grid
        ListView
          ListView.DataTemplate
            UserControl uc2 (DataContext = base.MyClass1.MyClass2)
              Grid
                UserControl ucButtons
              Grid
            UserControl uc2
          ListView.DataTempate
          ListView.PanelTemplate
            UniformGrid
          ListView.PanelTemplate
        ListView
      Grid
    UserControl uc1
  Grid
Window
```

So how can I get access to the MyClass1-objext?

I found out that I can walk the tree using `.Parent`, but can only do that to a certain point:

```
Grid gScheduleControlBar = btn.Parent as Grid;
UserControl ucScheduleControlBar = gScheduleControlBar.Parent as UserControl;
Grid gDay = ucScheduleControlBar.Parent as Grid;
UserControl ucDay = gDay.Parent as UserControl;
//ucDay.Name confirms it's the userControl defined
Grid grid = ucDay.Parent as Grid;
// grid.Name="" and grid.Parent = null
```

so from here there is no further way upwards, which means I can't pass the `UserControl` 'border'.

Any ideas?
As fallback-option there is of course the way of storing a reference of `MyClass1` in `MyClass2`.

EDIT => Final Result:
`<Button x:Name="Del" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor AncestorType=UserControl AncestorLevel=3}}"`

Comment: If you want to do this via Bindings, you can use `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor AncestorType=whatever}`, from code you can use the `VisualTreeHelper` to get the visual parent of any control.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer totallly agree with you, that this would work, but only in a scenario, where the ancestorType is always the same.
So this would limit my usage of 'UserControl ucButton' as it can only be used where a `UserControl (ancestorType)` exists.
Any ideas without limitation?

Comment: If you want the same solution for every case, then *something* has to stay the same. If you know for example that you want to get the parent's parent every time, you could use `AncestorType=FrameworkElement` and specify an `AncestorLevel` to indicate an Element higher up in the hierarchy. You would have to account for auto-generated ContentPresenters however. In the example you included in your question it looks like `AncestorType=UserControl` and `AncestorLevel=2` should work.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Aaah...I thought I would need to specify my `UserControl` by its name directly and not so broad as `UserControl`.
Works flawless.
Would you be so kind and turn that into an answer?

Comment: Sure, give me a minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this via Bindings, you can use `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor AncestorType=yourNamespace:YourType}`, from code you can use the `VisualTreeHelper` to get the visual parent of any control.

If there are multiple parents of that type in your hierarchy can can additionally specify an `AncestorLevel`. In the example you included, it looks like `AncestorType=UserControl` and `AncestorLevel=2` should work.